# GWT focus element vs Javascript focus

Tags: javascript, gwt, vaadin

I am trying to understand what is the difference between focus() method called from Vaadin component (which points to GWT focus() method on element) and javascript executed in browser which set focus to the element with simple focus method.

GWT:

```
/**
* Gives keyboard focus to this element.
*/
public final native void focus() /*-{
   this.focus();
}-*/;
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').focus();
```

When I use GWT for setting focus the element behaves like it gets focus by keyboard (it gets additional :focus css class). With usage of javascript this style is not added. Where is a real difference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any real differences between GWT `focus()` and Javascript element `focus()` since they are calling the same method under the hood.

In the snippet below, I called the Javascript `focus()` on button click. The `<a>` gets the correct `:focus` CSS style when it is focused pragmatically.

```js
function doFocus() {
    document.getElementById("testAnchor").focus();
}

function doBlur() {
    document.getElementById("testAnchor").blur();
}
```

```css
a:focus, a:active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="testAnchor" href="#">This is a test link</a>

<p>Click the buttons to focus or blur the above test link.</p>
<p>The link should turn red when it is focused.</p>

<input type="button" onclick="doFocus()" value="Focus">
<input type="button" onclick="doBlur()" value="Blur">
```

Comment: I was testing javascript behavior by using script called from Chrome Console.